# tableView:commitEditingStyle got called for the row that should not be deleted

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In recent , I am getting a crash on the line of commitEditingStyle: forRowAtIndexPath (My tableView got only 1 section)

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ((indexPath.row > 2 && [_answer.agreeUsers count] == 0) || (indexPath.row > 3 && [_answer.agreeUsers count] > 0)) {
        iKMAppDelegate *appDelegate = (iKMAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        NSUInteger step = 3;
        if ([_answer.agreeUsers count] > 0) {
            step = 4;
        }
        Comment *comment = [_comments objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row - step)];
        return [appDelegate.appDataObject.currentUser isEqualToString:comment.createdBy];
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        NSUInteger step = 3;
        if ([_answer.agreeUsers count] > 0) {
            step = 4;
        }

        Comment *currentSelectedComment = [_comments objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row - step)];
}
```

the crash was the last line in  commitEditingStyle,And 
from the crash log

```
*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 18446744073709551612 beyond bounds [0 .. 11]
```

it seems the commitEditingStyle got called for the indexPath(0,0)(because 18446744073709551612 is -4 in unsigned integer,so the indexPath.row must be 0), but it's obviously that i can only return YES in canEditRowAtIndexPath when the indexPath.row is larger than 3 or 4, so for the row = 0 , canEditRowAtIndexPath always return NO.How can the indexPath with row = 0 be called for deleted for commitEditingStyle?

Comment: There is an indexing problem, may be index is not properly intialized.

Comment: Can you provide the exact code in the method canEditRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @GouravJoshi but the index is be given by the system , so i think it should be initialized

Comment: @Unni i 've already add the  complete the full implementation of the canEditRowAtIndexPath , it will return NO for indexPath with row = 0 , isn't it?

Comment: Yes It will return 0. Are you  updating  _comments array from some other thread ?. Otherwise app should crash in canEditRowAtIndexPath method in line  Comment *comment = [_comments objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row - step)]. right?

Comment: it seems won't be another thread here , and i think even it has such a thread doing such thing , it still won't call commitEditingStyle with a indexPath that row is 0

Comment: Since _comments is a mutable array, It is poosible to have necessary data  at canEditRowAtIndexPath method and It will be removed/updated (by some other thread) befre calling commitEditingStyle method. You should log the _comments array count and its objects at each method.

Comment: ok , I 'll try it first ,thanks @Unni